# jquery event which is called when the readonly value of the text box is changed automatically

Tags: jquery

Is there any jquery event which is called when the readonly value of the text box is changed automatically

I want to  call an event (jquery) which should be called when the readonly value of the textbox is changed some how by other jquery events.

Early Reply is highly appreciated.

Best Regards,
Sagar

Answer (score 2):

There is no event for this (not one you would want to attach to, a general DOM change event handler would have *horrible* performance).

If you expanded on the context a bit, there may be another solution to get what you're after, for example what's setting it to readonly?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a change event to your `<input>` and test for the readonly attribute:

```
$('input').change(function(){
    if($(this).attr('readonly') == true){
        // do something fancy
    } 
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question...this checks for an attribute when a `change` event from something *else* happens.  Since it's `readonly` that event won't fire, since the person won't be focusing/bluring the element.  Also, this checks for the *presence* not the *change* of the `readonly` attribute.

Comment: I realized that a few minutes after posting - apparently the coffee hasn't kicked in yet...

Answer (score 0):

would the change() method not work?

```
$('input:readonly').change(function() {
   alert("Readonly input changed!!");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function that will be executed every `N` seconds (via `setInterval`) and check for the field value. It is very ugly, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well as of my knowledge and research is saying that you have to do this way : http://jsfiddle.net/kmvSV/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input[id$=_txtTest]').bind("change", function () {
     alert($(this).val());
   });
   $('button').bind("click", function () {
     $('input[id$=_txtTest]').val('hello').trigger('change');
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like Sagar Dixit said in his answer, you can trigger the change event manually.

```
// trigger the change event as soon as you set new value to the readonly field
$('input').val(newValue).trigger('change')
...
...
// Listen to the change event
$('input').change(function() {
  // Handle the change
})
```